# Is there a way to update an MVC 5 ViewModel from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an MVC 5 ViewModel I am trying to update by using a hidden field as shown below:

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ModelAction, new { Value = "New" })
```

I ran the below JavaScript statements to test and see if I can update the ViewModel but it did not get updated. The hidden field does get updated but not its bound model property called ModelAction. The ViewModel property ModelAction was initially set to a value of "New" and was supposed to be updated to a value of "Browse" when the hidden field was set to a value of "Browse" but this is not happening:

```
$('#ModelAction').val("Browse"); //set value in hidden field
var modelActionFromHtml = $('#ModelAction').val(); //check if hidden field value was set
var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //load Model 
var modelActionFromViewModel = viewModel.ModelAction; //check if value in model updated
```

I thought the ViewModel was data bound in 2 directions so updates to the View fields would update the model but this is not happening in the above test. Is there a way I can update my ViewModel from JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

This will not give the updated model because @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) is done during the server-side rendering of the html.

```
var viewModel = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)); //load Model 
var modelActionFromViewModel = viewModel.ModelAction; //check if value in model updated
```

So before those scripts are ran, the `var viewModel` already has a value, which is the one **fresh from your controller** because it was just rendered.

---

What you might need to do is do the client side equivalent by using `$(formElement).serialize()` and converting it to json via `JSON.Stringify()`;
Be sure to put your element inside a form tag.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#ModelAction').val("Browse"); //set value in hidden field
   var modelActionFromHtml = $('#ModelAction').val();

   var viewModel = var data = JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray());
   console.log(viewModel);
});
```